# SELECT 1 ID and all belonging elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to create a json select query which can give me back the result on next way.
1 row contains 1 main_message_id and belonging messages. (Like the bottom image.) The json format is not a requirement, if its work with other methods, it will be fine.

I store the data as like this:

```
+-----------------+---------+----------------+
| main_message_id | message | sub_message_id |
+-----------------+---------+----------------+
|               1 | test 1  |              1 |
|               1 | test 2  |              2 |
|               1 | test 3  |              3 |
|               2 | test 4  |              4 |
|               2 | test 5  |              5 |
|               3 | test 6  |              6 |
+-----------------+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to create a query, which give me back the data as like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------+--+
| main_message_id |        message        |  |
+-----------------+-----------------------+--+
|               1 | {test1}{test2}{test3} |  |
|               2 | {test4}{test5}{test6} |  |
|               3 | {test7}{test8}{test9} |  |
+-----------------+-----------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_agg() for that:

```
select main_message_id, json_agg(message) as messages
from the_table
group by main_message_id;
```

Note that `{test1}{test2}{test3}` is invalid JSON, the above will return a valid JSON array e.g. `["test1", "test2", "test3"]`

If you just want a comma separated list, use string_agg();

```
select main_message_id, string_ag(message, ', ') as messages
from the_table
group by main_message_id;
```